# É possível usar o Value do Input como seletor CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Vejam os exemplos abaixo. Eu estou tentando estilizar meu CSS através do `value` que ele tem, mas não esta dando certo.

Montei 3 exemplos, um para que se o `input` tiver o `[value="red"]` ele deve ficar com uma borda vermelha. Porém mesmo vc digitando `red` nele nada muda, e se ele já vier com o value definido como `red`, mesmo vc apagando esse valor ele continua com a borda vermelha.

Também fiz um teste com o select, já deixando uma opção com o `option[value="3"]` selecionada usando `selected` o CSS tb não é aplicado...

**Existe alguma forma de usar o `value` que está no *input* e usa-lo como seletor para aplicar alguma classe *apenas com CSS*?**

```css
[value="red"] {
    border: 2px solid red;    
}
select > option[value="3"] {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
Digite "red" nesse input e nada acontece<br>
<input type="text" value="" />
<br><br>
Esse input já está com o value=red e o CSS funcionou, <b>mas se eu apagar ele continua com o estilo!</b><br>
<input type="text" value="red" /><br><br>
Esse Select já está com o option de value=3 selecionado, mas nada acontece<br>
<select name="qa_contact">
    <option value="1">opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">opt 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">opt 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A um tempo atrás eu fiz uma pergunta no SO-EN sobre o mesmo assunto: [How to select a row that contains a column with a specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049783/how-to-select-a-row-that-contains-a-column-with-a-specific-text)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É preciso diferenciar duas coisas no atributo `value` de um input:

- o valor atual (o que você vê)
- a propriedade do elemento (`defaultValue`)

Quando você define um valor ao atributo `value`, esse valor é adicionado à propriedade `defaultValue` que só pode ser alterada via JavaScript. Alterar o valor do campo, seja digitando ou pelo método `.value` do JavaScript, o `defaultValue` permanece o mesmo, e é essa referência para a qual o seletor do CSS aponta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A única forma de alterar o `defaultValue` é alterando o atributo do elemento no DOM:

```js
function f(){
   var e = document.querySelector("input");
   e.setAttribute("value", e.value);
}
```

```css
[value="red"] {
    border: 2px solid red;    
}
```

```html
Digite "red" no input e clique no botão "OK":
<br>
<input type="text" value="">
<br>
<button onclick="f()">OK</button>
```

Ou seja, simplesmente digitando um novo valor no campo não altera seu atributo. Nem mesmo usando `elemento.value = "red";` irá alterar a propriedade `defaultValue`.

No caso do `select` mencionado, devido a restrições visuais próprias do elemento `option`, não é possível atribuir-lhe uma borda (exceto quando o select for do tipo `multiple`, e não são todos os navegadores que suportam isso), mas ele aceita outras propriedades, como `color` ou `background`:

```css
select > option[value="3"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<select name="qa_contact">
    <option value="1">opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">opt 3</option>
</select>
```

Borda no `option` com `select multiple` (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Edge):

```css
select > option[value="3"] {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<select name="qa_contact" multiple>
    <option value="1">opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">opt 2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">opt 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Informações interessantes, pelo visto parece que apenas com CSS não seira possível no momento...